# Testing Apollo Query with React Hook Client

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-apollo

I am trying to write test for this component using jest

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

import { updateYourDetails } from 'universal/domain/health/yourDetails/yourDetailsActions';
import Input from 'universal/components/input/input';
import InputNumber from 'universal/components/input/inputNumber/inputNumber';
import AsyncButton from 'universal/components/asyncButton/asyncButton';
import ErrorMessage from 'universal/components/errorMessage/errorMessage';
import Link from 'universal/components/link/link';
import analytics from 'universal/utils/analytics/analytics';
import { isChatAvailable } from 'universal/logic/chatLogic';
import { validators } from 'universal/utils/validation';
import { localTimezone, getWeekdays } from 'universal/utils/date';
import {
  CALL_ME_BACK_LOADING_MSG,
  CALL_ME_BACK_LABELS_SCHEDULE_TIME,
  CALL_ME_BACK_LABELS_SELECTED_DATE,
  CALL_ME_BACK_ERROR_MSG,
  CALL_ME_BACK_TEST_PARENT_WEEKDAY,
  CALL_ME_BACK_TEST_CHILD_WEEKDAY,
} from 'universal/constants/callMeBack';

import CallCenterAvailibility from './CallCenterAvailibility';
import SelectWrapper from './SelectWrapper';
import SelectOption from './SelectOption';
import styles from './callMeBackLightBox.css';
import { CALL_ME_BACK_QUERY } from './callMeBackQuery';
import postData from './postData';

export const CallMeForm = props => {
  const initSelectedDate = getWeekdays()
    .splice(0, 1)
    .reduce(acc => ({ ...acc }));

  const { onSubmissionComplete, className, variant } = props;
  const [hasSuccessfullySubmitted, setHasSuccessfullySubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [apiStatus, setApiStatus] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [cellNumber, setCallNumber] = useState(props.cellNumber || '');
  const [customerFirstName, setCustomerFirstName] = useState(props.customerFirstName || '');
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(props.Number || '');
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(initSelectedDate || '');
  const [scheduledTime, setScheduledTime] = useState('');

  const weekdays = getWeekdays() || [];
  const timezone = localTimezone || '';
  const requestReceived = apiStatus === 'CALLBACK_ALREADY_EXIST';

  const cellNumberInput = useRef(null);
  const customerFirstNameInput = useRef(null);

  const getQuery = () => (
    <Query query={CALL_ME_BACK_QUERY} variables={{ weekday: selectedDate.weekday }}>
      {({ data, error, loading }) => {
        if (loading)
          return (
            <SelectWrapper disabled labelTitle={CALL_ME_BACK_LABELS_SCHEDULE_TIME} name="scheduledTime">
              <SelectOption label={CALL_ME_BACK_LOADING_MSG} />
            </SelectWrapper>
          );
        if (error) return <ErrorMessage hasError errorMessage={<p>{CALL_ME_BACK_ERROR_MSG}</p>} />;
        return (
          <CallCenterAvailibility
            selectedDate={selectedDate}
            callCenterBusinessHour={data.callCenterBusinessHour}
            onChange={val => setScheduledTime(val)}
          />
        );
      }}
    </Query>
  );

  const getPostSubmitMessage = (firstName: string, type: string) => {
    const messages = {
      callCentreClosed: `a`,
      requestReceived: `b`,
      default: `c`,
    };
    return `Thanks ${firstName}, ${messages[type] || messages.default}`;
  };

  const validate = () => {
    const inputs = [customerFirstNameInput, cellNumberInput];
    const firstInvalidIndex = inputs.map(input => input.current.validate()).indexOf(false);
    const isValid = firstInvalidIndex === -1;

    return isValid;
  };

  const onSubmitForm = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    onSubmit();
  };

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    if (variant === '0' && !validate()) {
      return;
    }

    analytics.track(analytics.events.callMeBack.callMeBackSubmit, {
      trackingSource: 'Call Me Form',
    });

    setIsLoading(true);

    const srDescription = '';
    const response = await postData({
      cellNumber,
      customerFirstName,
      number,
      scheduledTime,
      timezone,
      srDescription,
    });
    const { status } = response;

    const updatedSubmissionFlag = status === 'CALLBACK_ALREADY_EXIST' || status === 'CALLBACK_ADDED_SUCCESSFULLY';

    // NOTE: add a slight delay for better UX
    setTimeout(() => {
      setApiStatus(apiStatus);
      setIsLoading(false);
      setHasSuccessfullySubmitted(updatedSubmissionFlag);
    }, 400);

    // Update Redux store
    updateYourDetails({
      mobile: cellNumber,
      firstName: customerFirstName,
    });

    if (onSubmissionComplete) {
      onSubmissionComplete();
    }
  };

  if (hasSuccessfullySubmitted) {
    return (
      <p aria-live="polite" role="status">
        {getPostSubmitMessage(
          customerFirstName,
          (!requestReceived && !isChatAvailable() && 'callCentreClosed') || (requestReceived && 'requestReceived')
        )}
      </p>
    );
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmitForm} className={className}>
      {variant !== '1' && (
        <>
          <label htmlFor="customerFirstName" className={styles.inputLabel}>
            First name
          </label>
          <Input
            className={styles.input}
            initialValue={customerFirstName}
            isMandatory
            maxLength={20}
            name="customerFirstName"
            onChange={val => setCustomerFirstName(val)}
            ref={customerFirstNameInput}
            value={customerFirstName}
            {...validators.plainCharacters}
          />
        </>
      )}
      {variant !== '1' && (
        <>
          <label htmlFor="cellNumber" className={styles.inputLabel}>
            Mobile number
          </label>
          <Input
            className={styles.input}
            initialValue={cellNumber}
            isMandatory
            maxLength={10}
            name="cellNumber"
            onChange={val => setCallNumber(val)}
            ref={cellNumberInput}
            type="tel"
            value={cellNumber}
            {...validators.tel}
          />
        </>
      )}
      {variant !== '1' && (
        <>
          {' '}
          <label htmlFor="number" className={styles.inputLabel}>
            Qantas Frequent Flyer number (optional)
          </label>
          <InputNumber
            className={styles.input}
            disabled={Boolean(props.number)}
            initialValue={number}
            name="number"
            onChange={val => setNumber(val)}
            value={number}
          />
        </>
      )}
      {weekdays && (
        <>
          <SelectWrapper
            testId={`${CALL_ME_BACK_TEST_PARENT_WEEKDAY}`}
            labelTitle={CALL_ME_BACK_LABELS_SELECTED_DATE}
            name="selectedDate"
            onChange={val =>
              setSelectedDate({
                ...weekdays.filter(({ value }) => value === val).reduce(acc => ({ ...acc })),
              })
            }
            tabIndex={0}
          >
            {weekdays.map(({ value, label }, i) => (
              <SelectOption
                testId={`${CALL_ME_BACK_TEST_CHILD_WEEKDAY}-${i}`}
                key={value}
                label={label}
                value={value}
              />
            ))}
          </SelectWrapper>
          {getQuery()}
        </>
      )}
      <AsyncButton className={styles.submitButton} onClick={onSubmit} isLoading={isLoading}>
        Call me
      </AsyncButton>
      <ErrorMessage
        hasError={(apiStatus >= 400 && apiStatus < 600) || apiStatus === 'Failed to fetch'}
        errorMessage={
          <p>
            There was an error submitting your request to call you back. Please try again or call us at{' '}
            <Link href="tel:134960">13 49 60</Link>.
          </p>
        }
      />
    </form>
  );
};

CallMeForm.propTypes = {
  cellNumber: PropTypes.string,
  customerFirstName: PropTypes.string,
  number: PropTypes.string,

  onSubmissionComplete: PropTypes.func,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  variant: PropTypes.string,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { frequentFlyer, yourDetails } = state;

  return {
    cellNumber: yourDetails.mobile,
    customerFirstName: yourDetails.firstName,
    number: frequentFlyer.memberNumber,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CallMeForm);
```

My test file is as below

```
    import { render, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/test-utils';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MockDate from 'mockdate';
import { isChatAvailable } from 'universal/logic/chatLogic';


import { CALL_ME_BACK_QUERY } from './callMeBackQuery';
import { CallMeForm } from './CallMeForm';
import postData from './postData';

jest.mock('universal/components/input/input', () => 'Input');
jest.mock('universal/components/asyncButton/asyncButton', () => 'AsyncButton');
jest.mock('universal/components/errorMessage/errorMessage', () => 'ErrorMessage');
jest.mock('universal/logic/chatLogic');
jest.mock('./postData');

describe('CallMeForm', () => {
  let output;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    const mockQueryData = [
      {
        client:{},
        request: {
          query: CALL_ME_BACK_QUERY,
          variables: { weekday: '' },
        },
        result: {
          data: {
            callCenterBusinessHour: {
              timeStartHour: 9,
              timeStartMinute: 0,
              timeEndHour: 5,
              timeEndMinute: 0,
              closed: false,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ];


    const { container } = render(<MockedProvider mocks={mockQueryData} addTypename={false}><CallMeForm /></MockedProvider>);
    output = container;
  });

  afterEach(cleanup);

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(output).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I keep getting error: TypeError: this.state.client.stop is not a function

I also removed `<MockedProvider>` wrapper and I got another error Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as a prop. Wrap the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient instance in 
via props.

Does anyone know why I get this error and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have not the solution, but I've got some information.

First of all, I'm having the same error here, rendering with `@testing-library/react`.

I then tried to render with ReactDOM, like that:

```js
// inside the it() call with async function
const container = document.createElement("div");
ReactDOM.render(
    < MockedProvider {...props}>
        <MyComponent />
    </MockedProvider>,
    container
);

await wait(0);
expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
```

And also tried to render with Enzyme, like that:

```js
// inside the it() call, with async function too
const wrapper = mount(
    <MockedProvider {...props}>
        <MyComponent />
    </MemoryRouter>
);

await wait(0);
expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Both ReactDOM and Enzyme approaches worked fine.
About the error we're getting, I think maybe it's something related with `@testing-library/react` =/

I didn't tried to render with `react-test-renderer`, maybe it works too.

Well, that's what I get... maybe it helps you somehow.

Ps.: About `waait`: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-final-state

---

**EDIT 5 Feb 2020:**

Based on https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/pull/2165#issuecomment-478865830, I found that solution (it looks ugly but works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯):

```
<MockedProvider {...props}>
    <ApolloConsumer>
        {client => {
            client.stop = jest.fn();
            return <MyComponent />;
        }}
    </ApolloConsumer>
</MockedProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it. I had a missing peer dependency.

Your package.json is not shown so I am not sure if your problem is the same as mine but I was able to resolve the problem by installing "apollo-client".

I am using AWS Appsync for my client and hence did not have apollo-client installed.